# Can't login to SQL server due to connection trigger

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I've created a trigger that was supposed to get all the instances of logs, but there must be an error inside the trigger itself and now the trigger, by security, block the access of everyone on the server and I can't do nothing to delete the trigger without connecting to the database/server.

Does anyone know a solution to delete the trigger with cmd or anything else?

Comment: If you want to audit access to SQL Server, use SQL Server's audit features. Don't try to roll your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally resolved the problem, I didn't needed to use the DAC.

Just by using

sqlcmd -S [name of the server]

then

DISABLE TRIGGER [name of the trigger] On all server

then

go

and it was ok :)

Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to connect to the SQL Server on the dedicated administrator connection. To use the connection you must connect locally from the Windows Host. (unless you have allowed remote connections).

To use the connection:
In the Connect to Database Engine dialog box, in the Server name box, type ADMIN: followed by the name of the server instance. For example, to connect to a server instance named ACCT\PAYABLE, type ADMIN:ACCT\PAYABLE.

You can also check this link for more information on disabling login triggers:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326598.aspx

Comment: I tried your solution and an error occured saying : "The  administrator dedicated connection are not supported by SSMS, because he is etablishing many connection by conception. "Sorry for my rough translation.

Comment: Did you follow linked MSDN article, Disable Login Trigger part?

Comment: for future reference you can connect via SSMS just not through object explorer.